# How to auto size a combobox in EXT JS 5.0.1?

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5, autosize

{
xtype: panel,
layout: 'form',
columnWidth: 0.3,
items: [
{
xtype: 'combo',
fieldLabel: 'Sample'
}]}

Answer (score 0):

With the `grow` config option, you can make the field grow to the size of the content (optionally up to a maximum width) https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-grow

Answer (score 0):

Use [hbox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox.html) layout for you panel with flex property for you.
Or vbox if you want the rest of the fields to be lower.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/35gf)